# Отмена центрирования

Tags: html

Всё находится по центру. Необходимо, чтобы "Электронная почта" и "Пароль" находились от начала текстового поля. Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лучше б разметку html выложили и css........ а так можно все что угодно городить,  float left  или text-align: left или еще чёрт знает что, в зависимости от разметки

Comment: Легко: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srPtf.png

Comment: @Other, СУПЕР!!!!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, а как жо! :) Жаль только на тяп-ляп, но качественно делать не буду, вдруг это и требуется, а мне не заплатили за работу?

Comment: @Other, я даже и не подумала об этом варианте решения! =))))

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, да кто знает при такой формулировке? Дано изображение, значит потенциальный тэг "photoshop".

Comment: Ну человек первый раз тут задает вопрос, поэтому простительно.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, не знал что в первый раз нет осознания того, что мы тут не телепаты и не можем ничего сделать без кода и что это простительно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этих "Электронная почта" и "Пароль" это могут быть `<label>` или `<span>` или просто `<div>` (вот именно к ним) задать:

```
text-align: left;
```

Например:

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}



/* доп. стили */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #66bcf7;  
  border-top: 5px solid #2aa4f7;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}

input {  
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

label {  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;  
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="row-form">
      <label>Электронная почта</label> 
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="email@com.ru">
    </div>
    
    <div class="row-form">
      <label>Пароль</label> 
      <input type="text" name="text" id="passs" value="****">
    </div>
</form>
```

От начала формы ввода (если правильно понимаю что Вы вообще хотите):

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
}



/* доп. стили */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #66bcf7;  
  border-top: 5px solid #2aa4f7;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}

input {  
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1rem;  
}

label {  
  color: #fff; 
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.row-form {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="row-form">
      <label>Электронная почта</label> 
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="email@com.ru">
    </div>
    
    <div class="row-form">
      <label>Пароль</label> 
      <input type="text" name="text" id="passs" value="****">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Для `span` и `label` тогда ещё нужно задавать `display: block`.

Comment: Текст будет слева от начала экрана, а нужно, чтобы от начала формы ввода.

Comment: @Артур, 1. Нужно добавлять свой html/css для решения подобных задач. 2. Хоть бы как-то нарисовали что Вы хотите (Текст будет слева от начала экрана, а нужно, чтобы от начала формы ввода).

Comment: Вам памятник нужно поставить - за бескорыстную помощь :)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko поэтому надо закрывать невнятно заданные вопросы с просьбой правки и особенно со скрином, а не отвечать

Comment: У меня было свободное время, поэтому не жалко) И вдруг мне кто-нибудь так бескорыстно поможет)))